# Multiple ROS installation on single machine

Tags: ros, ros2, linux, installation

Can I have multiple versions of ROS or ROS2 installed on a single machine or PC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. See discussion here: https://answers.ros.org/question/187548/can-i-install-multiple-ros-version-on-the-same-machine/

Each ROS distro (both 1 & 2) installs its programs into `/opt/ros/{distro}`, so you can have them installed side-by-side with no conflict.

However you should only **use** one distro at a time. In order to use a distro, you source its setup script in your shell, e.g.:

```
$ source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash
...the remainder of this session will be in the humble environment
```

If you plan to have multiple ROS versions installed and use them regularly, I would **not** recommend doing this inside your `.bashrc` or equivalent login script, because you need to avoid having multiple distros sourced in the same shell. Whenever you want to start using a distro, just source its setup script manually.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks it helped. but I have a doubt. Generally the source scripts are added to the .bashrc file or what ever shell you may use for convenience . So here in case of multiple versions of ROS being installed we cannot add both of the sourcing script to the bash file right?

Comment: Correct, you cannot source _both_ distros in the same shell. That's why I recommended that you _don't_ put it in .bashrc for convenience. You can make a simple function for convenience, such as `chros() { source /opt/ros/$1/setup.bash }` => `chros humble`